# UIImageView going to top left of cell when setting width and height constraints.

Tags: ios, uitableview

[image]

I'm setting 50 / 50 for width and height and trying to set it ten from the top and ten from the left side, but when I run the app the view gets pushed all the way to the top left.

I've completely removed all restraints and started from scratch on the tableview, and it's still a problem.

Never had this problem before, any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

While set constraint to any UIController uncheck "checkbox constraint to margin" display in Image and then set constraint and try again. May it will help you. 
[image]